# store the picturebox image to a database

Tags: c#, sql, picturebox

I have a Picture box. The image in the picture box is a static one. I am loading the image from the resources folder. I am not able to read the static image from the picture box and store it in the database. here is my code.

```
 private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image votingBackgroundImage = pictureBox5.Image;
        Bitmap votingBackgroundBitmap = new Bitmap(votingBackgroundImage);
         Image votingImage = (Image)votingBackgroundBitmap;
            var maxheight = (votingImage.Height * 3) + 2;
            var maxwidth = votingImage.Width * 2;
            if (maxheight == 227 && maxwidth == 720)
            {

                 System.IO.MemoryStream defaultImageStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                 Bitmap NewImage =new Bitmap(votingImage,new Size(720,227));
                 Image b = (Image)NewImage;
                  b.Save(defaultImageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                 defaultImageData = new byte[defaultImageStream.Length];
              }
    }
```

Query I used to add the image in the database:

```
            String MyString1=string.format("insert into question_table(background_image) Values(@background_image)");
            com = new SqlCommand(MyString1, myConnection);
              com.Parameters.Add("@background_image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = defaultImageData;
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I check this in the sql database.It stores the value as **0 x000000...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just creating the `byte[]` but you never actually copied the content

try

```
 System.IO.MemoryStream defaultImageStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
 Bitmap NewImage =new Bitmap(votingImage,new Size(720,227));
 Image b = (Image)NewImage;
 b.Save(defaultImageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
 defaultImageData = new byte[defaultImageStream.Length];
 //assign byte array the content of image
 defaultImageData = defaultImageStream .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're allocating an array of bytes to store your stream's content, but you don't copy the content itself.

Maybe you don't need an intermediate array. Try using the [ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) method of `MemoryStream`:

```
b.Save(defaultImageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
// ...
com.Parameters.Add("@background_image", SqlDbType.Image).Value
    = defaultImageStream.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store it as a Blob i.e byte array.